# how to display arranged data in graph

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I want to 1) sort the data frame by specific column which contains both characters and numbers and 2) to output this in graph in same order of arrangement

In my data frame, I have a column (Column B) which contains some rows with characters and some rows with numbers.
ex.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | UN |
| Cell 3 | BY |
| Cell 3 | 1 |
| Cell 3 | 2 |
| Cell 3 | PD |

I want to sort the data frame by Column B in a specific way [UN, PD, BY then by numbers in ascending order 1,2].
I was somewhat successful in doing that by doing this: df %>% arrange(column B)
which will spit out something like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 3 | BY |
| Cell 3 | PD |
| Cell 1 | UN |
| Cell 3 | 1 |
| Cell 3 | 2 |

but

1. I can't seem to specify the order of lettered cells (its either going to be in 'ascending' or 'descending', can't seem to specify specific order in non-alphabetical order. ex - UN then PD then BY instead of BY, PD, UN or UN, PD, BY]
2. Even after arranging the column in ascending way, when I plot it by
   p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Column B, y=Column A) + geom_point()
   x - axis will start with numbers first followed by letters [ex. x-axis order from left to right: 1,2,BY, PD, UN]

Answer (score 1):

Convert Column B into a factor with your specified levels. This will plot the x axis in the desired order. You can optionally `arrange` your data frame by it too:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(`Column B` = factor(`Column B`, c("UN", "PD", "BY", 1:9))) %>%
  arrange(`Column B`)

df
#>   Column A Column B
#> 1   Cell 1       UN
#> 5   Cell 3       PD
#> 2   Cell 3       BY
#> 3   Cell 3        1
#> 4   Cell 3        2

ggplot(df, aes(x = `Column B`, y = `Column A`)) + geom_point()
```

[image]